# Deleting duplicates on combination of two columns in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table for example :
Port Table

| S No | A Port | B port |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 80 | 100 |
| 2 | 90 | 110 |
| 3 | 100 | 80 |
| 4 | 94 | 106 |

I want to delete record no. 3 as it is having same combination as record no. 1 how to do this in oracle ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a single `MERGE` statement and the `ROW_NUMBER` analytic function combined with `GREATEST` and `LEAST` to find and delete the duplicates:

```sql
MERGE INTO table_name dst
USING (
  SELECT ROWID rid,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
           PARTITION BY LEAST(A_Port, B_Port), GREATEST(A_Port, B_Port)
           ORDER BY S_no
         ) AS rn
  FROM   table_name
) src
ON (dst.ROWID = src.rid AND src.rn > 1)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET A_port = NULL
  DELETE WHERE 1 = 1;
```

Which, for your sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (S_No, A_Port, B_port) AS
SELECT 1,  80, 100 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2,  90, 110 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 100,  80 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4,  94, 106 FROM DUAL;
```

Will delete the 3rd row.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=2a34c008062c5628c787861b64d4da3e)*

Answer (score 0):

Tried this in mysql, do some test/scenarios

```
SELECT P1.* FROM port_tbl AS P1 
LEFT JOIN port_tbl AS P2 ON P1.port1 = P2.port2 OR P1.port2 = P2.port1 
WHERE P1.id < P2.id OR ISNULL(P2.id) 
ORDER BY P1.id;
```